# Show that if the product of $n$ consecutive $4$-digit positive integers is divisible by $2910^2$ then $n \geq 6$

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that the product of $n$ consecutive $4$-digit positive integers is divisible by $2910^2$. What is the least possible value of $n$?

**My attempt** Factoring gives $$2910^2=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 97^2,$$ but I can't see what to do from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Since $97^2 = 9409$ and $2 \cdot 97^2 > 10^4$, $9409$ is the only four-digit number with a factor of $97^2$. Thus, any such sequence $S$ of consecutive positive numbers whose product $P$ is divisible by $2910^2$ either contains $9409$ or must contain two distinct multiples of $97$, in which case $S$ has at least 98 terms.

Since the product $P$ is divisible by $5^2$, $S$ must contain a multiple of $5^2 = 25$ or two multiples of $5$. The closest multiple of $25$ to $9409$ is $9400$, so in the former case $S$ has length at least $10$. The multiples of $5$ immediately less than and above $9409$ are $9405$ and $9410$, and the sequence $(9405, \ldots, 9410)$ has six terms, which is a lower bound for the length of $S$.

> We can now show that the product of these six numbers in fact is divisible by $2910^2 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 97^2$, and hence that the minimal length of $S$ is $6$ as claimed. In particular two of these six numbers are multiples of $3$, so the product is divisible by $3^2$, and three of these numbers are multiples of $2$, so the product is divisible by $2^3$ and hence by $2^2$. Thus, the product of this sequence is divisible by $2910^2$. (In fact, at least one of the three multiples of $2$ is a multiple of $4$, so the product is divisible by $2^4$ and hence by $2^2 \cdot 2910^2 = 5820^2$.)  By construction this is the only solution with length $6$. Similar reasoning shows that there is a unique solution with length $7$, namely, $(9409, \ldots, 9415)$.